# Ratchet Websockets Serverside Basics

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, websocket, ratchet

Now i Don't really understand this serverside part of websockets at all.
I was into AJAX request for a realtime/constant/periodic update to client from server just when i heard about Websockets.

I am able to install Ratchet on my WAMP server.

**clienttest.php**

```
<script>
var conn = new WebSocket('ws://localhost:8080/rachet/servertest.php');
conn.onopen = function(e) {
    console.log("Connection established!");
    conn.send('Hello World!');
};

conn.onmessage = function(e) {
    console.log(e.data);
    //do something using e.data
};
</script>
```

**servertest.php**

```
    require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';


    use Ratchet\Server\IoServer;
    use Ratchet\Http\HttpServer;
    use Ratchet\WebSocket\WsServer;
    #now i have no idea how to do
```

*What happened in traditional Ajax(with json) was...*

```
$somedata1 = $_POST['somedata1'];
$somedata2 = $_POST['somedata2'];

//1) check database 2)do something 3) send data back to client

echo json_encode(array("data1"=>$data1,"data2"=>$data2));
```

Now i want to know that how can this code above can be written in Ratchet/websocket form with unaltered meaning.

**In short** :  How do I receive and then send some data to client ?

**P.S**: I have been through all the Ratchet docs but i didn't find anything simple to make me understand.

Comment: https://blog.samuelattard.com/the-tutorial-for-php-websockets-that-i-wish-had-existed/

This is a blog post I wrote ages ago with a really simple ratchet example

Comment: you could probably try to explore this package https://github.com/sacky-server